# Как сделать сделать такой график? С использованием библиотеки PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, matplotlib, pyside2

Как сделать из стандартного графика `widget` вот такой
(красным цветом отмечен нужный) стиль.

[image: Красным цветом отмечен нужный стиль]

Стандартный график

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что есть сейчас:

```
    # Смена цвета графика на белый
    self.widget_2.setBackground('w')
    # Название графика widget
    self.widget_2.setTitle("Fe", color="b", size="12pt")
    # Добовляются названия осей координат
    styles = {"color": "#f00", "font-size": "12px"}
    self.widget_2.setLabel("left", "C(Fe общ.), мг/дм3", **styles)
    self.widget_2.setLabel("bottom", "Hour(H)", **styles)

    self.widget_2.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
```

Comment: Красным отмечен график, создаваемый методом plot.

Comment: @passant я знаю как создаются графики. Вопрос как сделать той стиль оформления графика?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-overview.html

Comment: @AlexanderChernin вы скидываете как построить график. А мне нужно как поменять стиль со стандартного черного графика но такой как в фото выше. Про построение и изменение кривизны линии я знаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не написали с использованием какой библиотеки
вы хотите строить графики.
Вот вам похожая реализация того что вы хотите
с использованием *matplotlib*.

*Matplotlib* — библиотека на языке программирования Python
для визуализации данных двумерной графикой.

Изучайте и экспериментируйте.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#from Matplotlib_graphs_design import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(750, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 127);")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.frame)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius:20px;\n"
"border: 2px solid #000000;\n"
"}")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_2)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"\n"
"border: none;\n"
"}")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label)
        self.graph_one = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.graph_one.setObjectName("graph_one")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.graph_one)
        
        self.verticalLayout_3.setStretch(0, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setStretch(1, 5)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame_2, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.frame_3.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius:20px;\n"
"border: 2px solid #000000;\n"
"}")
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_3)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_3)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"\n"
"border: none;\n"
"}")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.graph_two = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.graph_two.setObjectName("graph_two")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addLayout(self.graph_two)
        
        self.verticalLayout_4.setStretch(0, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setStretch(1, 5)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame_3, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.frame_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.frame_4.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius:20px;\n"
"border: 2px solid #000000;\n"
"}")
        self.frame_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_4.setObjectName("frame_4")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_4)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_4)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"\n"
"border: none;\n"
"}")
        self.label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.graph_three = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.graph_three.setObjectName("graph_three")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addLayout(self.graph_three)
        
        self.verticalLayout_6.setStretch(0, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setStretch(1, 5)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame_4, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.frame_5 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.frame_5.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius:20px;\n"
"border: 2px solid #000000;\n"
"}")
        self.frame_5.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_5.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_5.setObjectName("frame_5")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_5)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_5)
        self.label_4.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
"\n"
"border: none;\n"
"}")
        self.label_4.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.graph_four = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.graph_four.setObjectName("graph_four")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addLayout(self.graph_four)
        
        self.verticalLayout_8.setStretch(0, 1)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setStretch(1, 5)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame_5, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Matplotlib graphs"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "График N° 1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "График N° 2"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "График N° 3"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "График N° 4"))
        

class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):     
        self.fig , self.ax = plt.subplots(1, dpi=100, figsize=(5, 5), 
            sharey=True, facecolor='white')
        super().__init__(self.fig) 

        names = ['15', '25', '30', '35','40']
        colors = ['red','red','red','red', 'red']
        _size = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]

        self.ax.bar(names, _size, color = colors)
        self.fig.suptitle('Гистограмма',size=9)


class Canvas_2(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):     
        self.fig , self.ax = plt.subplots(1,dpi=100, figsize=(5, 5), 
            sharey=True, facecolor='white')
        super().__init__(self.fig) 

        names = ['Клубника', 'Ананас', 'Лайм', 'Виноград']
        colors = ['blue','yellow','aqua','fuchsia']
        _size = [20, 26, 30, 24]
        exploit = [0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05] 

        plt.title("Количество фруктов",
            color='black',size=9, family="Arial")

        self.ax.pie(_size, explode = exploit, labels = names, 
            colors = colors,
                autopct = '%1.0f%%', pctdistance = 0.6,
                shadow=True, startangle=90, radius = 0.8, 
                labeldistance=1.1)  
        self.ax.axis('equal')


class Canvas_3(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):     
        self.fig , self.ax = plt.subplots(1, dpi=100, figsize=(5, 5), 
            sharey=True, facecolor='white')
        super().__init__(self.fig) 

        self.fig.suptitle('График данных',size=9)
        np.random.seed(20)
        y = np.random.randn(150).cumsum()

        self.ax = plt.axes()
        plt.plot(y, color='magenta')


class Canvas_4(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):     
        self.fig , self.ax = plt.subplots(1, dpi=100, figsize=(5, 5), 
            sharey=True, facecolor='white')
        super().__init__(self.fig) 

        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7]
        y1 = [1, 0, 1, 3, 2,4,3]
        y2 = [0, 2, 2, 3, 4,6,5]
        y3 = [3, 1, 3, 4, 2,7,6]

        y = np.vstack([y1, y2, y3])

        labels = ["Y1 ", "Y2", "Y3"]
        color = ["orange", "blue", "green"]

        self.ax.stackplot(x, y1, y2, y3, labels=labels,colors=color)
        self.ax.legend(loc='upper left')
        self.ax.stackplot(x, y)
        self.fig.suptitle('Stackplot graph', size=9)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.canvas = Canvas()
        self.canvas1 = Canvas_2()
        self.canvas2 = Canvas_3()
        self.canvas3 = Canvas_4()

        self.graph_one.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.graph_two.addWidget(self.canvas1)
        self.graph_three.addWidget(self.canvas2)
        self.graph_four.addWidget(self.canvas3)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)
     w = MainWindow()
     w.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Ну, если вы знаете, как создаются графики, то наверняка так-же знаете, что встроенных стилей в matplotlib не так уж много, и за несколько минут их можно пересмотреть. Правда некоторые из них столь близки, что разницу заметить невооруженным глазом весьма непросто, особенно на линейном графике.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i, style in enumerate(plt.style.available+['default']):
    plt.figure(i)
    plt.style.use(style)
    print(style)
    x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    y=[3,2,4,5,3,4,5]
    z=[1,2,3,4,3,4,5]
    plt.title(style)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.plot(x,z)
    plt.show()
```

Если же ни один из этих стилей вас не удовлетворит, то сделать свой график, подобрав  по вкусу или по заданному примеру соответствующие параметры стиля -  тоже задача не архисложная.

Comment: вылезает ошибка "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\PyCharm\Gui_Программы\Python\New\SL_lke2.py", line 173, in buttonChart_Ph
    for style in plt.style.available:
NameError: name 'plt' is not defined"

Comment: Вы же сказали, что графики вы строить умеете? Как же вы их строите без подключения matplotlib? . Это же стандарт! Ну ладно, исправлю код, если это для вас это представляет трудность.

Comment: просто я строил графики без matplotlib через стандартные настройки PyQt5. Так что не знаю как строить через него в widget

Comment: С QT я работал очень давно, и не уверен, что там есть возможность менять весь стиль сразу. Но менять элементы - точно есть. Что то вроде setStyle, QwtPlotCurve, QPolygon и пр.

Comment: все что знаю представленное выше. Но, там изменяется только цвет графика и добавляется стека и все.